# Dynamically allocated array using a typedef struct

Tags: c++

I've been given this code for a struct:

```
struct Part /*A Part record*/
{
    int ID;
    float Price;
    int Quantity;
};
typedef Part *Partptr;
// Part record pointer type; The type Partptr becomes synonymous with Part *
typedef Partptr* Index;
// The type Index becomes synonymous with Partptr *
```

I'm confused on what the typedefs below it are doing. Later in the program, I'm trying to define a dynamically allocated array of this struct using the provided variable `Index DBindex`, but when I try doing so like this:

```
DBindex = new Index[];
```

I get an error:

> a value of type "Index *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Index"

I thought Index *was* a pointer, based on the typedef. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you want to go down the `new[]` road? `std::vector` is right there.

Comment: Hint: `new[]` returns a pointer to the given type. `X* = new X[...]` can work, but `X = new X[...]` cannot. In all honesty these `typedef` declarations are junk and only create confusion.

Comment: FWIW, if you want a dynamic array of `Part`s, use a `std::vector<Part>`

Comment: Since the OP wants a dynamic array of pointers, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Part>>` would likely be more appropriate.

Comment: @tadman C++ gave whole new meaning to the term "newb".

Comment: @user4581301 `B* b = new B`.

Answer (score 6):

`Partptr` is an alias for `Part*`, and `Index` is an alias for `Partptr*` (aka `Part**`).

`Index DBindex = new Index[];` doesn't work, because `new` returns a `T*` pointer for whatever type of `T` it creates, ie:

```
T* ptr = new T;
```

```
T* ptr = new T[size];
```

So, if `DBindex` really needs to be an `Index` (aka `Part**`), then you need to `new[]` a type that is equivalent to `Part*`, such as `Partptr`:

```
Index DBindex = new Partptr[size];
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
Part** DBindex = new Part*[size];
```